# Looking for the logotype font used in the AprilSix logo

Tags: font-identification

[image]

Just looking for this font - or something similar if you have it. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **Ubuntu Bold** or **Explora**, but rather second one. Check this link:

[Fonts](https://www.dafont.com/explora.font)

Comment: Great, thanks for that. I tried it in the WhatTheFont tool from myfonts and got no good results.

Comment: Glad I could help;)

Comment: @SylwesterPilarz the fontsquirrel link was dead for me, so I proposed an edit with a link to dafont.com, which does not rely on a token.